# Language (translator) ZF2, Route URL reset

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want the following method on language select:

on `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` I want to detect language by

```
getRouteMatch()->getParam('language', null)
```

and then replace language-part in URL and set the new one.

Like this:

original url request is "/en/signup" and I want to set new one on MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE as "/signup".

How can I set new url for following routing?
May be the better way is exist?